# Раскодировать послание

Tags: кодировка, перекодировка

Дано:
Текст в неизвестной кодировке. Нужно узнать, что за кодировка и представить в читабельном виде

P����� ��j�� h�l� k ��m��� m���l� b���� �i�limi�li � �� k���v�n� ��p���� kodek � ��k��v��� ��k�m����� P��h���.

Попытался решить задачу так:

```
with open("tmp.txt", encoding="windows-1250") as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

Перебирая самые популярные кодировки из этого списка:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings

Успеха это не принесло.
Какие еще есть варианты?

Comment: или файл был дважды перекодирован...

Comment: Для оказания помощи нужен как минимум сам файл, а не его отображение в виде текста на сайте (которое при этом ещё несколько раз перекодировано).

Comment: Спасибо, работа с оригиналом помогла решить задачу